# wazone 2100 cutscenes

Tags: software-installation

I'm new to Ubuntu 14.04LTS, I ran ubuntu a few years back and hove now returned and its all oh so different!!

Anyway my problem is I have installed warzone 2100 from the software manager and would like to add the cutscenes, which I have downloaded, however I cant for the life of me work out how to do it, falling at the first hurdle of not being able to work out where it has default installed (software manager didnt give me any options). Please excuse my ignorance and treat me as a total newbie, I cant remember much of what I'd learnt before.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  They got rid of the menu structure where you could find the application information by right clicking on the menu item.

I do know for a fact that Lubuntu still uses menus.

If you have that window manager installed, you can pull that information from there.

I'm sure there is a better way, but you could install Lubuntu desktop boot into it at the login screen and find out where it is.

another way is by using find |grep warzone

Comment: Thanks for your response, glad I'm not going mad, was sure I used to right click and it would tell me the path lol. whats this find grep warzone? obviously its a terminal command but does that find the install directory for me? Thanks

Comment: well... if you go to the root directory
cd /
then issue:
find -nowarn |grep warzone
 will find all instances of warzone on your system